# Simple JSP page with jsf giving JasperException

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, servlets

This is the Error log:

> type Exception report
>
> message An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views>/mob_admin_only/themHS.jsp at line 19
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP >page /WEB-INF/views/mob_admin_only/themHS.jsp at line 19
>
> Stacktrace:
>
> > org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWra>pper.java:574)
> >     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:4>76)
> >     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
> >     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
> >     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
> >       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> >       Servlet.themHSServlet.doGet(themHSServlet.java:27)
> >       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
> >       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
> >       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> >       Filter.PermissionFilter.doFilter(PermissionFilter.java:43)
> >       Filter.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:41)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> > javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.setJspId(UIComponentClassicTagB>ase.java:1856)
> >     org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.mob_005fadmin_005fonly.themHS_jsp._jspx_met>h_f_005fview_005f0(themHS_jsp.java:181)
> >     org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.mob_005fadmin_005fonly.themHS_jsp._jspServi>ce(themHS_jsp.java:147)
> >       org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
> >       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
> >     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:4>38)
> >       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
> >       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
> >       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
> >       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> >       Servlet.themHSServlet.doGet(themHSServlet.java:27)
> >       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
> >       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
> >       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> >       Filter.PermissionFilter.doFilter(PermissionFilter.java:43)
> >       Filter.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:41)>
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache >Tomcat/8.0.24 logs.

Here are my jsp page:

```
16:     <div id="content">
17:         <jsp:include page="../header.jsp" />
18:         <h1>Nháº­p há»“ sÆ¡ thĂ­ sinh - KĂ¬ tuyá»ƒn sinh 2015</h1>
19:         <f:view>
20:                 <h:form >
21: 
22:                     <!--content-->
```

I'm a newbie about JSF, what going wrong here?

Comment: You are not clear about the exception as to when exactly it is thrown. Try giving a reproducible example with your environment especially the JSF version you happen to use.

Comment: In the future, always copypaste the exception message and 1st line of stacktrace (without parentheses/linenumber) into a search engine for possible clues/answers.